# How to fetch HttpOnly cookie value in LWC?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience

We have 3rd party Non-SF apps that uses Salesforce Credential as Oauth provider. When we hit 3rd party application login link, it navigates to Community login page.

**Requirement :** I want to add expid in out experience portal login page to detect the 3rd party application name.

Below is the link to extend Endpoint with Experience Id:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_identity_dynamic_extend_endpoint_expid.htm&type=5

and after doing inspect element, our 3rd party Non-SF application shows below URL.

**site-url/services/oauth2/authorize/expid_value**

I tried to pass "appName" as value directly as below and it works.

**e.g. site-url/services/oauth2/authorize/expid_appName**

Now, In Broswer cookies it shows value as below and this value is something I want to fetch.

[image]

I tried to use document.cookie in LWC but it seems Javacript do not fetch the cookies which are HttpOnly.

**LWC JS:**

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

    export default class DisasterNotifications extends LightningElement {
        connectedCallback(){
            this.getCookie();
        }
        
        getCookie() {
            var tr = this.retriveCookie();
            if(tr != ''){
                this.cookieVal = JSON.parse(tr);
            } else{
                this.cookieVal = [];
            }
             
            console.log('Cookie val:'+this.cookieVal);
        }
     
        retriveCookie(){
            const cookieName = 'expid_appName';
            var cookieString = "; " + document.cookie;
            var parts = cookieString.split("; " + cookieName + "=");
            return decodeURIComponent(parts.pop().split(";").shift());
        }
    }
```

Based on below link I even tried to create a VF page but there is no option to add VF page component to Community Login page and my Community login page uses standard login page component(dont want to build custom login page).

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_identity_dynamic_with_custom_login_page.htm&type=5

I also tried to pass VF page variables to LWC via Aura app but again there is no option to add Aura app to Community Login page.

There is no clear information from below links where I can fetch HttpOnly cookies value directly in LWC.

Can someone please suggest how can I fetch HttpOnly cookie in LWC? Any other possible options is also fine.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to rethink your solution architecture in terms of flows and experience id: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224780/can-a-login-flow-know-which-connected-app-started-it/

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. The point of `HttpOnly` is to prevent this type of cookie reading. If it were that easy to circumvent, it wouldn't be a very useful security feature. You'll have to go with a custom login page if you want to be able to do this.

Comment: I have found possible workaround for this. From LWC , I am calling Controller class and In controller I just added System.Site.getExperienceId() and returning the same and I am able to read the value perfectly!

Comment: The only problem is it does not clear cookies. If I close the browser and try again without expid value, it still refers old cookie values.

Comment: When it sets the expid value in cookie, it by default sets expiry date as 1 month from current date. Is there a way to control this? e.g. If I close the browser and this time if I do not pass anything, it still refers existing cookie value. If I clear cookies then only it works as expected but clearing cookies from browser is not possible. So basically if is there a way to set expiry date of this cookie ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_sites.htm

Comment: @DhananjayPatil The cookies are controlled by the service that set the cookie. That service must be configured to not set an Expires attribute on the cookie, which will tell the browser that it is a session cookie, which will be cleared when the browser is closed.